# yielding data from multiple sources in parallel

Tags: .net, asynchronous, yield-return

I have a situation where I would like to stream data of the same type from several sources asynchronously.  The data results should go out as they comes in.  What is the easiest way to do this?  yield return is blocking so this is not doing what I want.  In the example below I would like the data from source B to output before the data from source A.

```
List<string> GetComputerRecordsFromA(int computerId)
{
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return new List<Record> {"Record1","Record2","Record3"};
}

List<int> GetComputerRecordsFromB()
{
    return new List<int> {"Record1","Record2","Record3"};
}

IEnumerable<List<int>> GetDataBlocks()
{
    //How to yield out in the order data comes available?? 
    var computerIds = new List<int> {1,3,99,4};
    foreach(int id in computerIds)
    {
        yield return GetDataFromA();
        yield return GetDataFromB();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first function should probably return `List<int>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do things concurrently - use a `BlockingCollection` and a few threads. One thread for each input and one - your main thread probably - that yield-returns items from the list.

Just note that you might not reach the end of the list - if your reader is faster than your writers, it will think it got to the end of the list even though the writers will write more data to the list later.

Comment: In situations where the reader is faster than the writers it is good to use [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you run out of items but have not finished filling the collection the enumerable will block on `.GetNext()` until more data is available.

Comment: But blocking collection (as its name implies) blocks if there are no items available. The question specifically says to avoid blocking.

Comment: You can't avoid blocking an IEnumerable if there are more items that haven't arrived yet. If you don't want that, you have to use a different interface, and not use yield-return in the first place. OP asked specifically about yield return.